# Laravel Passport Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

i use Laravel passport for auth

in route api.php

```
Route::get('/todos', function(){
  return 'hello';
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

but when open localhost:8000/api/todos I see the following error

```
 InvalidArgumentException
Route [login] not defined.
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
}

/**
 * Get the URL for a given route instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
 * @param  mixed  $parameters
 * @param  bool   $absolute
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
 */
protected function toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute)
{
    return $this->routeUrl()->to(
        $route, $this->formatParameters($p
```

I want if the user was not authenticated
Do not redirect to any page and only see the page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you enter above-mentioned URL directly in browser search bar?
If you did its wrong way because you also need to enter API token with your request__!!

To check either request includes token or not make your own middleware.

Command to create Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckApiToken
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

change middleware handle method to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!empty(trim($request->input('api_token')))){

        $is_exists = User::where('id' , Auth::guard('api')->id())->exists();
        if($is_exists){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
        return response()->json('Invalid Token', 401);
}
```

Like This
Your Url should be like this

http://localhost:8000/api/todos?api_token=API_TOKEN_HERE

Comment: I opened in the browser 
And I did not use postman because I wanted to see the output in the browser too
I did not send the API token because i wanted to see error   without user authenticatin

Comment: so better to make your own middleware to check that request includes token if yes than is this verified token..!!

Comment: I am going to update my Question wait for it 
Hope it will help

Comment: i see error for not found /middleware/user class . so i add use app/user to apitoken middleware .

Comment: but i see this error now . Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found . Should I add auth to this middleware ? @blue-moon

Comment: need to include use Auth

Answer (score 94):

Use Postman and set the Header `Accept: application/json` otherwise Laravel Passport would never know it's an API client and thus redirect to a /login page for the web.

see below image to see where to set the accept parameter:
[image]

Comment: I also experience that issue and I tried adding `Accept: application/json` but still the issue persist. I'm using laravel/passport 7.0.2

Comment: Having the same issue here. The header was set but nothing happened, the error persists. Tried also adding `Authorization: Bearer` (with an empty token since I'm going to the login page)

Answer (score 8):

You also have to add another header Key: Accept and value: application/json

Answer (score 8):

**Check Your Header Request to put**

> Authorization = Bearer {your token}

Comment: In addition to checking what is being sent by header not by params

Comment: you must add this to ```header```

Answer (score 4):

In the following of [@Eki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10178490/eki) answer,

This error is because you didn't set "Accept" field in your headers.

**To avoid this error**, add a middleware with priority to Authenticate to check that:

1. add an extra middleware with below handler

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       if(!in_array($request->headers->get('accept'), ['application/json', 'Application/Json']))
           return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);

       return $next($request);
   }
   ```
2. set priority in app/Http/Kernel.php

   ```
   protected $middlewarePriority = [
       ...
       \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class, // new middleware
       \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
       ...
   ];
   ```
3. add new middleware to your route

   ```
   Route::get('/todos', function(){
       return 'hello';
   })->middleware('MyMiddleware', 'auth:api');
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You also have to add another header Key: X-Requested-With and value: XMLHttpRequest