# Auth::user()->id returns "Trying to get property of non-object" -- Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

### UPDATED 2

I made like and unlike method. But when I try to like the article, it returns an error. `Route [login] not defined.`

I am using passport API login. I am giving token for login etc... I login without a problem. I see the the pages only auth user can see. But it seems when I like the article, `Auth::` doesn't understand user logged in or not. Maybe this is the problem. Because I am using Passport? So in the controller instead of `Auth::`

I used it like `$user = $request->user();` (you can see the controller below.) But still same error popping when I like the article. `Route [login] not defined.`

**controller**

```
public function postLikeArticle( Request $request, $articleID )
{
    $article = Article::where('id', '=', $articleID)->first();
    $user = $request->user();

    $article->likes()->attach( $user->id, [
        'created_at'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]);

  return response()->json( ['article_liked' => true], 201 );
}

public function deleteLikeArticle( Request $request, $articleID )
{
    $article = Article::where('id', '=', $articleID)->first();
    $user = $request->user();

    $article->likes()->detach( $user->id );

    return response(null, 204);
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::get('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@postLikeArticle');
    Route::get('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@deleteLikeArticle');

});
```

If you need to see anymore file. please name it in the comment.

Comment: Is anyone logged in?

Comment: dd(Auth::user()); and see what it returns this may help narrow down the problem

Comment: @apokryfos yes, logged in.

Comment: And what **exactly** does that `dd` call return? Don't guess, attach the output to your question

Comment: it returns null `Route [login] not defined.`  @NicoHaase But I am doing token(laravel passport) based login. SPA with vue. And I logged in without a problem. I can see the routes for only auth user.

Comment: @parabellum can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294253/laravel-passport-route-login-not-defined) answer?

Comment: @nakov did the exact thing but nope, no effect still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your routes for like/dislike are not `auth` protected which means that the user might not be logged in, so you can group all routes requiring an authenticated user like this:

```
// public routes out of the group, for example:

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::get('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@postLikeArticle');


    // you cannot have same routes for both, so this
    // Route::get('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@deleteLikeArticle');
    // should be this:
    Route::get('/articles/{id}/dislike', 'Api\ArticlesController@deleteLikeArticle');

});
```

Then either: `Auth::id()` or `Auth::user()->id` should give you the same. Or even the helper function so you don't need to worry for the imports..

```
auth()->id();

// or
auth()->user()->id;
```

Comment: okay, I tried your code and I am a bit confused here :) because now I am returning this. `Route [login] not defined.` I am doing token(laravel passport) based login. SPA with vue. And I logged in without a problem. I can see the routes for only auth user.

Comment: What my code does it wraps up all the auth protected routes in a group. So instead of adding the `middleware` to each route separately, you make a group. 

You still need `Auth::routes()` out of the group. Not all the routes need to be auth protected

Comment: okay `Auth::routes();` searching for the wrong place for login. because now It returns this:

Comment: I don't get another error to help you. Just make sure that the routes that need logged in user are in the group and the other routes that you have in your routes file is out of the group.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I uptaded the question, explanation. could you check it out please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194827/discussion-between-nakov-and-parabellum).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the user to be authenticated then you need to be using the middleware that ensures that. In addition you need to also ensure that you are using the correct HTTP verbs depending on what you need to do, if anything your current definition is creating a conflict:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@postLikeArticle');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->delete('/articles/{id}/like', 'Api\ArticlesController@deleteLikeArticle');
```

You also need to ensure your front-end is using the correct verbs as well.

There are two reasons:

1. If you don't use the middleware you're basically saying those routes don't require authentication
2. If you're using the API guard to authenticate users then you need to explicitly use the `auth:api` middelware otherswise Laravel will attempt to authenticate the user using the default guard which is usually the session. When using an API you should not use the session

Comment: I updated the question and could you check it out please?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Auth::user()->id
```

You can try this

```
auth()->user()->id
```

you can refer  [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#included-authenticating) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Few simple points should resolve your confusion:

1. "Trying to get property of a non object" means, `Auth::user()` is not an object which means it's null, you are trying to access a route publicly which needs an authenticated user which leads to our next point.
2. Routes which use functions `postLikeArticle()` and `deleteLikeArticle()` should be inside the authorization middleware `'auth:api'`
3. You are using method `get` for both of your routes which use above functions, one should be using `delete` method.
4. You can use `Auth::id()` as a substitute of `Auth::user()->id` just to be short hand.

When using PASSPORT for authentication, you do not follow the usual Laravel way of user authorization hence Auth::user() is useless. In order to fetch the authenticated user, you need to use:

`$user = $request->user();`

Where `$request` is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Here is an example for you:
Import the Request class in the beginning of the controller file:

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

and your controller logic:

```
public function postLikeArticle( Request $request, $articleID )
{
    $article = Article::where('id', '=', $articleID)->first();
    $user = $request->user();

    $article->likes()->attach( $user->id, [
        'created_at'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at'    => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ]);

  return response()->json( ['article_liked' => true], 201 );
}

public function deleteLikeArticle( Request $request, $articleID )
{
    $article = Article::where('id', '=', $articleID)->first();
    $user = $request->user();

    $article->likes()->detach( $user->id );

    return response(null, 204);
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I updated the question and could you check it out please?

Comment: how can I use it inside the code? could you give me an example?

Comment: @parabellum updated the answer to show you use case

Comment: thank you for the update. I tried it but still having the same error: `Route [login] not defined.`

Comment: @parabellum dude, that is already a different issue now than the one with which you have initialized this thread. Your problem was to get the authroized user properly and that has been resolved. Now for this new problem, open a new issue, you cant debug your whole code in one issue. makes sense?