# Issue with creating an API with laravel and laravel passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i am trying to start a simple API with Laravel Passport.
i am following [this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-secure-api-php-laravel-passport)
i have sucessfully completed it, however when i try accessing "http://localhost:8000/api/CEO" in a browser without specifying a bearer token, i am getting the error:
`Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [login] not defined.`

now i understand bearer token is needed to authenticate requests, but how can i verify that the api requests have a token? and if they dont, show an error. Instead of redirecting to a login page that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at laravel git repository you will find the `Authenticate.php` middleware: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
/**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
```

What's happening at your end is that you are missing a very important header in your request `Accept: application/json`, therefore Laravel is trying to redirect to the login page which is not defined in your `api.php` routes.
Just hit your endpoint with postman or something similar by adding that header and you will receive an `Unauthenticated` error message.

If you want to open that URL from your browser you can also add a middleware to process the request and return a `401` error message.
I made my own middleware wich attaches the token sent by URL to my request headers.
If no token is present in URL then abort by throwing a `401` error

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ParseTokenFromUrl
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->has('access_token') && !$request->headers->get('Authorization')) $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->get('access_token'));
        if (!$request->headers->get('Authorization')) abort(401);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Please also refer to [Laravel Passport Route [login] not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294253/laravel-passport-route-login-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

The "auth:api" middleware in api.php corresponds to `App/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`.
(this is verifiable by checking $routeMiddleware in `App/Http/Kernel.php`)

in this middleware we check :
`if (! $request->expectsJson()) { return route('login'); }`
change the return to
`return abort(502, 'Invalid request');`
to instead show an error.