# How can i get user id using passport in laravel api?

Tags: php, laravel, api, controller, laravel-passport

i am trying to retrieve user ID using auth

what i have tried so far:

```
public function testfun()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    return $id;
}
```

it return:

```
ErrorException: Attempt to read property &quot;id&quot; on null
```

i tried:

```
public function testfun(Request $request)
{
    return Auth::user()->id;
}
```

i got the same error

i tried to place the API within the middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
Route::get('testapi', [RegisterController::class, 'testfun']);
});
```

and call it with guard:

```
public function testfun(Request $request)
{
    return auth('api')->user();
}
```

i got:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [/login] not defined.
```

here is the full Route of API:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::post('login', [RegisterController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
Route::get('logout', [RegisterController::class, 'logout']);
Route::get('user', [RegisterController::class, 'user']);
Route::post('changePassword', [RegisterController::class, 'changePassword']);
Route::get('testapi', [RegisterController::class, 'testfun']);
});
});
```

when i place this route under the first group(auth):

```
Route::get('testapi', [RegisterController::class, 'testfun']);
```

and try this on controller:

```
return auth()->user();
```

i will get response 200 but it doesn't show anything

here is my login function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|string|email',
    'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email','password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Unauthorized'
    ],401);
    }

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Authorized Successfully!',
        'access_token' => $tokenResult-> accessToken,
        'token_type'=> 'Bearer',
        'expires_at'=> Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        'userData' => $this->user($request),
    ]);
}
```

in the above after login i am able to see the user details under 'userData' as showing below from Postman

```
{
"message": "Authorized Successfully!",
"access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC....",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_at": "2023-12-05 11:18:07",
"userData": {
    "id": 1,
    "fullname": "Admin",
    "email": "admin@gmail.com",
    "roles_id": 2,
    "role": "Admin"
}
}
```

i even tried to place it alone in the API route as showing below:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/usertest', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user()->id;
});
```

and i got this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [/login] not defined
```

i have been trying to get the ID of the authenticated user but with no luck

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: which request ?

Comment: Are you passing the authorization header in your request?

Comment: for login request?

Comment: no for `testapi` where you're fetching user details.

Comment: usually i will call Auth to fetch user details but it doesn't seems to work here, that's why i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

in Postman i had to set this header `Accept: application/json` otherwise Laravel Passport would never know it's an API client and thus redirect to a /login page for the web. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681131/19663907

and also for Authorization in Postman (Bearer Token) placed the token in it after login

and used the function as showing below:

```
public function testfun(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->user()->id;
    $currentUser = DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->get();

        return $currentUser;
}
```